# Call Service function and change the view

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Javascript and angular.js. I am working on app to show direction between address using google api.I have a question related to calling the function and change the view. In a view-controller, searchAccount/searchAccount.js I allow user to select the certain account.. 
In a different location view , I show the direction between selected. To pass the data between view , I am using service...I call the service function and use $lcoation to change the view.  However, in the service function , I am not able to get the element of location.My Service functon runs before the location view loaded.

```
$scope.showMaps = function(){
               $location.path('/locations');
               //getDirections.showDirections($scope.accountCheckList);
               getDirections.mapOnPage($scope.accountCheckList);
          }
```

In mapOnPage , I am not able to pick the elements of location.html.. What is the best practices around this. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a demo with the code you have? It is hard to understand from this alone.

Comment: What about providing us what u are trying to do in your service? Also what determines the location path? Besides you wont be able to call the service after setting the new location since it will change to the other view controller.